# UINavigationController pushViewController from tableViewController subclass

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, subclass, nib

I am seeing a strange app behaviour when I try to push some view controller from uitableviewcontroller subclass.

Let me explain it first. I have created main nib which is linked to rootViewController (appDelegate) that is inside navigationController. In that nib a have added a `UITableView` and a custom `UITableViewController` subclass `News_TableViewController` like it's shown in the screenshot:

[image: nib connections]

When I try to execute the code bellow I get nothing:

```
My_WebView *webView = [[My_WebView alloc] initWithNibName:@"My_WebView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:webView animated:YES];
```

Then I checked self.navigationController object but i gives me NULL:

```
NSLog(@"OBJ: %@",self.navigationController);
```

How is that I am not geting the reference to the `navigationController` despite of my custom class actually lives under navigationController ?

Thanks

Comment: In which method of the tableViewController are you pushing webView?

Comment: I used it in viewForFooterInSection method. But it also does not work elsewhere. NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController) always return NULL.

Comment: I think you should first put a breakpoint or NSLog in the TableViewController subclass' viewDidLoad method. Does it hit?

Comment: Yes, everything works fine except the part about navigationController. I have followed this [tutorial](http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/creating-pulse-style-scrolling-horizontally-scrolling-uitableview-as-a-subview-of-uitableviewcell/) to create pulse like tableView inside another tableView.

Comment: Probably is something wrong with the connection from rootViewController to this custom tableViewController. But where/how in the xib can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've mentioned, News_TableViewController is a UITableViewController, hence a UIViewController. I think you did'nt initialize the navigationController! A recommended way is to init the navigationController in your appDelegate class' delegate method as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc]init];
_navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

where RootViewController is the News_TableViewController class.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but that's not the case here. In appDelegate I do like this: navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController]; where self.viewController is UIViewController with xib. Well, in that xib I have defined News_TableViewController like you see on picture in my question...

Comment: I did it like you said. Removed not needed UIViewController and push News_ViewController instead. Works now. But it's really strange that did not work my way. Obviously I misconfigured something... Thanks!

Comment: I think this was the mistake in your appDelegate: initWithRootViewController:self.viewController. You should've initialized News_ViewController and then written initWithRootViewController:News_ViewController and the remaining commands stay as usual. The image you've provided is of News_TableViewController's xib right? So, u don't need to drag&drop the "News Table View Controller". the tableView delegate can handle that